# JSoup not working in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jsoup, universal-image-loader

I am creating an app to fetch XKCD comics (just for learning purpose). I am using JSoup to fetch comic title and url of the image and Universal Image Loader to post the image in ImageView. However I'm facing some problems. Here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

    ImageView xkcdImgIV;
    TextView titleTV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        xkcdImgIV=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.xkcdImgIV);
        titleTV=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTV);

        try{            
            new AsyncImg().execute(new String[]{"http://www.xkcd.com/"});
        } catch(NullPointerException e){
            Log.d(TAG,"Null pointer exception")
        }
    }
    private class AsyncImg extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{     
        Document doc;
        Elements elXkcdTitle;
        Elements elXkcdImgUrl;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) {
        try { 
                doc = Jsoup.connect(arg[0]).timeout(0).get();                
                elXkcdTitle=doc.select("#ctitle");
            elXkcdImgUrl=doc.select("#comic img");  

           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
        return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            titleTV.setText(elXkcdTitle.first().text());
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
      imageLoader.init( ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext() ));
            imageLoader.displayImage(elXkcdImgUrl.first().attr("src"), xkcdImgIV);

        }       
    }    
}
```

There is no network activity. I've given the Internet access permission to the app. Moreover Logcat doesn't show any error. Both Jsoup and Universal Image Loader JARS have been included in build path. Feel free to ask for additional info.

Comment: You are swallowing the exception in `doInBackground`. Try replacing `e.printStackTrace();` with `Log.e(TAG, e);` and see if Jsoup throws an exception.

Comment: @Jaap I replaced `e.printStackTrace();` with `Log.e(TAG, e);` .Logcat still didn't show any error.